# passing JSON objects to drush cvapi

Tags: api, drush

I'm building API extension that takes complex objects as parameters.

The API exporer does a brilliant job at parsing the objects, but drush less so.

Commands I am trying are:

```
`drush @contact cvapi Contact.getclif sequential=1 return="id" clif={"type":"raw","params":{"5":1,"6":1}} length=5`

`drush @contact cvapi Contact.getclif sequential=1 return="id" clif='{"type":"raw","params":{"5":1,"6":1}}' length=5`
```

Both fail to json_decode the object and my API method receives a JSON string.

I could decode the string in my API - but that feels a little hacky...

Am I doing something wrong?

[image: Screenshot of API explorer showing it working as expected]

Comment: If it is your objective is to execute API commands from the shell you can also use drush php-script.

Comment: oh right! thanks! thats a good plan @Kainuk - I guess I'm still wondering if this is a bug or user error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the drush api command needs to be made "json aware" it seems indeed. It shouldn't be too complicated, want to give it a go and patch it?

Comment: Thanks @xavier, i'm battling with `cv` first up... will see how I go! maybe :-)

Comment: Seems like we are moving toward `cv` as the standard cli tool over `drush` so probably ought to update the api explorer to reflect that change.

Comment: I would think adding cv but not removing drush makes sense

Answer (score 7):

Here is how to pass an array to drush

`echo '{"retrieval_parameters":{"jobId":97727336,"filePath":"Raw Recipient Data Export May 15 2017 22-07-43 PM 674.zip"}}'
| drush cvapi Omnirecipients.get --in=json`