# Is it possible to set the list of CiviCRM components from the command line using drush

Tags: installation, drush, cli, cv

`drush` and `cv` have both have commands to install extensions. But know I want to create a script that sets the CiviCRM components. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [passing JSON objects to drush cvapi](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16423/passing-json-objects-to-drush-cvapi) I found a solution:

```
echo '{"enable_components" :["CiviContribute","CiviMember","CiviMail","CiviReport","CiviEvent"] }' | drush cvapi Setting.create --in=json
```

Answer (score 2):

For those that use `cv` is also possible to use:

```
echo '{"enable_components" :["CiviContribute","CiviMember","CiviMail","CiviReport","CiviEvent"] }' | cv api Setting.create --in=json
```

Comment: For API4, the syntax is: `echo '{"values":{"enable_components":["CiviContribute","CiviMember","CiviReport"]}}' | cv api4 Setting.set --in=json` or `cv api4 Setting.set '{"values":{"enable_components":["CiviContribute","CiviMember","CiviReport","CiviPledge"]}}'`.